# finding minimum sum of absolute differences betweens values of two sets..

Tags: algorithms

given an array of numbers say a = [10, 11, 16, 15, 23] and b = [11, 8, 13],we have to find minimum sum of absolute difference between values from two arrays respectively...the remaining values in array of larger size can be neglected....
answer here wud be 4 the pairs wud be (|10-8| + |11-11| + |15-13|) = 4...
can we form any algorithm for that...i m nt sure if thats pure mathematics but any help wud be
eulogized..!

Comment: Farmer John, almost obsessive-compulsive in his organization of
dances, wants the spectacle to be as visually attractive as possible.
Thus, he wants to pair up the N bulls with cow partners such that
the total of all the magnitudes of differences in height is minimized.
Bulls have heights B_i (1 <= B_i <= 1,000,000) and cows have height
C_i (1 <= C_i <= 1,000,000). Of course, some cows will be unmatched
since N-M of them will have no partners; ignore their heights.

Comment: This seems to be a problem from [Sphere Online Judge](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DCOWS/). No idea if it's an active competition.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume the length of the first array **arr1** is smaller than or equal to the length of the second **arr2**. If it isn't, just swap them. First, **sort** both arrays, and let **dp[A][B]** be the smallest difference when you consider only the subarrays **arr1[A...]** and **arr2[B...]** (that is, **arr1** from **A** forward and **arr2** from **B** to the end). You have two choices:

- Pair **A** and **B**. In this case you'd get a total difference of **|arr1[A]-arr2[B]| + dp[A+1][B+1].**
- Don't use **B**. Note that in this case you'll never consider **B** again (because if you pair **A** and **B** to different elements, then you could swap both pairs and the sum would go down). So you can simply ignore **B** and your answer will be **dp[A][B+1]**.

Base cases:

- **dp[length of arr1][length of arr2] = 0**
- **dp[A][length of arr2] = infinity** (it's impossible to pair the remaining elements of arr1).